# How to stub getter or a method of freezed dataclass in Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, flutter-test, freezed

I have a freezed data class with some fields. A getter method returns nested elements of one attribute for easier access.

```dart
@freezed
class Airport with _$Airport {
  const Airport._();
  const factory Airport({
    required String identifier
    required String type,
    required List<Runway> runways,
  }) = _Airport;

  List<Ils> get allIls => runways
      .map((runway) => runway.allIls)
      .expand((ils) => ils)
      .toList();
}
```

I use the `Airport` class inside a test where the getter `allIls` is called. I don't want to fill `runways` with legit data, instead I directly want to stub the getter method `allIls` and have it return a list of objects.

What I tried:

Mock the Airport class:
`class MockAirport extends Mock implements Airport {}`

My test:

```dart
    test('',
        () async {
      final airport = MockAirport();
      final ilsList = [ils1, il2];
      when(airport.allIls).thenReturn(ilsList);

      expect(...);
    });
```

However, this gives me the following error:
`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Ils>'MockAirport.allIls`

I have also tried a "normal" method instead of a getter, with the same results:

```dart
  List<Ils> allIls2() => runways
      .map((runway) => runway.allIls)
      .expand((ils) => ils)
      .toList();
...

when(airport.allIls2.call()).thenReturn(ilsList);
```

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed a step in setting up your Mocks.

You need to add the [GenerateMocks](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/annotations/GenerateMocks-class.html) or [GenerateNiceMocks](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/annotations/GenerateNiceMocks-class.html) attribute somewhere in your library to auto-generate your Airport mocks. I like to have the attribute in the same file as my test, though that can lead to repeated mocks throughout your test files. After you have the attribute, you generate the mock using [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner).

Lastly, in your second example with the "normal" method, you don't need to add the `.call()` to your when statement. In fact, adding that will cause the call to fail. It should instead just be `when(airport.allIls2()).thenReturn(ilsList)`.

Comment: yeah I missed that, thanks! It works now